# Unable to read multi lines through CSV dataset config in jmeter only the second in the csv file is being read

Tags: jmeter

I have configured CSV dataset and inserted two records in the CSV file but while running the test case only one record is being used in the script. on the second iteration also same credentials are being sent

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have already  set to All threads , but still having this issue

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what exactly is wrong without seeing your [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) setup, however one thing is obvious: you don't have 2 iterations of the same virtual user, you have 2 virtual users.

Change [Sharing Mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/csv-data-set-config-in-sharing-mode-made-easy/) of the CSV Data Set Config to `All threads` and each virtual user will read the next line of the CSV file on each iteration:

[image]